# Select a Generic Type as a Model to Generate Strongly Typed View in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in ASP.NET MVC(3) when we want to add a new View we can select a type as a Model for generate a strongly typed view, but I try to select a generic Type and I can't find it in List, this maybe because a generic type is not a strongly type, but also there is must be a way to pass a type to T4, Does any one have any idea about it?

Comment: You can type whatever type you want, for example this is possible:
@model System.Collections.Generic.List<String>
Or maybe I didnt understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type whatever type you want, for example this is possible:

```
    @model System.Collections.Generic.List<String>
```

All the namespaces are not showed in the dialog for Add View, but you can type whatever you want.